# Returning javascript view in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In Ruby on Rails In my controller I can do something like this:

```
def jstest
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

This would return jstest.js.erb from the relevant views directory

jstest.js.erb

```
alert("Hello World")
```

The result being I get hello world alert.

I want to do the same thing in Laravel

In my controller I have:

```
public function jstest(  )
{
    return view('jstest');
}
```

in my view (which I have tried with both jstest.blade.js and just jstest.js)

but I get the error, view cannot be found.

The only way I get this to work is by calling the view jstest.blade.php and including my js in a `<script>` tag within this php file. but this feels a bit wrong...?

Is this even possible in Laravel? If so, where am I going wrong?

---

Example use case:

Imagine the following example, I have a table of comments, a user can click a delete button which will send an ajax request to delete the comment.

My Route:

```
Route::delete('post/comments/{comment}','commentsController@delete');
```

In my controller:

```
Public Function delete($comment)
{
    $comment->delete();

    return commentDeleted.js
}
```

commentDeleted.js:

```
$(#comment).remove();
```

So from the users perspective, they click delete and the comment disappears from their screen without loading a new page.

Comment: Basically, what you're after is a function that sticks some .js into HTML and lets you use it, without having to specify the HTML around .js file. Where's the actual issue then? Create a `jsview()` function which will include relevant JS file in some `.blade.php`. Also, why would anything feel wrong? It's dead simple, you have everything at your disposal. `view()` returns a `.blade.php` file from relevant directory. Extend this system as you feel fit.

Comment: Perhaps its just coming from Rails, but returning a php file with a HTML script tag seems like more effort than should be needed when what I really want is to simply just return Javascript. Why can I not just say `return view('jstest.js');`

Comment: Because `view()` fetches and executes a `.blade.php` view, which is some PHP mashed with HTML. `view('test')` returns `resources/views/test.blade.php`. As I mentioned, you can create your own function that does what you want. I'll post an answer about this.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. What you are saying makes perfect sense, I just thought there may be a more defined way of doing this.

Comment: @Brad as you have mentioned you are deleting with ajax right ? Then why you don't remove your comment after success of js. Just return true or false from controller .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Laravel supports this out of the box, but this is my take on your issue.

This is how I understood your problem: you want to specify a path to `.js` file as an argument to a function and you want this `.js` file to be immediately executed when loaded via browser.

I'd do it in these 2 steps

1. Create a `jsview()` function that accepts a path, similar to `view()`
2. Create the base `.blade.php` file which will be used by the above

#### The .blade.php contents

Assumption is that this view will be named `javascript.blade.php` and it's in `resources/views/` directory.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{$path}}"></script>
    </head>

    <body></body>

</html>
```

#### The function

```
function jsview($path)
{
    return view('javascript', ['path' => $path]);
}
```

#### Usage

```
<?php

Route::get('/test', function()
{
    return jsview('/assets/my.js');
});
```

This answer isn't really fully complete because your browser will be loading files from `public/` directory so all `.js` files you specify this way would be read from there. I believe Laravel does have something related to resources, but I'm not expert enough on that matter.

This is posted only to outline how to achieve something that you need, but isn't available out of the box.

Comment: But this would then attempt to load an enitre html page with just a js file on it? as oppose to just injecting some javascript into the existing page. Say for example I have a form on my page and when submitted I want make an ajax call to some route, that goes to my controller, does some stuff and then returns some javascript to manipulate the page, maybe displaying a message or something.

Comment: Yes, that would load an entire page with some JS on it. If you want to compose your views and share data between them, then there's always `@include` template function, if you're after template composition. The way I understood your question was that you wanted to execute some `.js`  in the browser without going through hassle with `<script>` tags. You can define a `.blade.php` file that includes several `.js` files and simply `@include('my_js_bundle')` in your target `.blade.php` view.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I have added a use case example to my question, hopefully this explains what I want to do. As I say, In rails this is simple, and you can even use js.erb which is the rails equivelant of blade to include php in your javascript. So you could pass it the comment id or something like that.

Comment: @Brad - would this be what you're after: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#extending-blade - extending blade with your custom directive, like `@js('my.js')` seems to be what you're after.